# Scope problem: varible in function not able to be used as argument in other function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, scope

I would like to use the userInfo dictionary in my getCreds() function as a parameter for my checkLogin() function, however making userInfo a global variable might but a solution but it won't be best practices. Any advice on how to make the userInfo dictionary accessible as checkLogin() arguments while using best practices? Note: I am required to use the parameters two in the checkLogin() function. Thanks!
Here is the code:

```
adminList = [
    {
        "username": "DaBigBoss",
        "password": "DaBest"
    },
    {
        "username": "root",
        "password": "toor"
    }
]

def getCreds():
    user_name = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter you password: ")
    userInfo = {"username":user_name, "password":password}
    return userInfo

def checkLogin(userInfo, adminList):
    for i in adminList:
        if userInfo == i:
            loggedIn = True
            print("YOU ARE LOGGEDIN!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the function `getCreds()` inside `checkLogin()` instead of trying to pass it as an argument. Something like this

```
def checkLogin(adminList):
    userInfo = getCreds() # <---- calling it inside the function
    for i in adminList:
        if userInfo == i:
            loggedIn = True
            print("YOU ARE LOGGEDIN!")

checkLogin(adminList)
```

**Output**

```
Enter your username: root
Enter you password: toor
YOU ARE LOGGEDIN!
```

If you insist on passing two parameters, you can do something like

```
def checkLogin(userInfo, adminList):
    for i in adminList:
        if userInfo == i:
            loggedIn = True
            print("YOU ARE LOGGEDIN!")

userInfo = getCreds()
checkLogin(userInfo, adminList)
```

Comment: That is a good solution however I'm requred to pass two parameters two the checkLogin function

Comment: @megatron_6560: Ok, check my edit and tell me if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def getCreds():
    adminList = [
        {
            "username": "DaBigBoss",
            "password": "DaBest"
        },
        {
            "username": "root",
            "password": "toor"
        }
    ]
    user_name = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter you password: ")
    userInfo = {"username": user_name, "password": password}
    return checkLogin(userInfo, adminList)

def checkLogin(userInfo, adminList):
    loggedIn = False
    for i in adminList:
        if i["username"] == userInfo["username"]:
            if i["password"] == userInfo["password"]:
                loggedIn = True

    if loggedIn == True:
        print("YOU ARE LOGGED IN !")
    else:
        print("INCORRECT CREDENTIALS !")
    return loggedIn

getCreds()
```